# problemin connecting apache superset running inside docker container to Kylin

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-superset, kylin

I have a running apache-superset inside a docker container that i want to connect to a running apache-kylin (Not inside docker ).
I am recieving the following error whenever i test connection with this alchemy URI : 'kylin://ADMIN@KYLIN@local:7070/test ':
[SupersetError(message='(builtins.NoneType) None\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)', error_type=<SupersetErrorType.GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR: 'GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR'>, level=<ErrorLevel.ERROR: 'error'>, extra={'engine_name': 'Apache Kylin', 'issue_codes': [{'code': 1002, 'message': 'Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected error.'}]})]
"POST /api/v1/database/test_connection HTTP/1.1" 422 -
superset_app             | 2021-07-02 18:44:17,224:INFO:werkzeug:172.28.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2021 18:44:17] "POST /api/v1/database/test_connection HTTP/1.1" 422 -

Comment: I think you need to get the IP address of the **docker0** interface. Try running `$ ifconfig` and look out for the **docker0** entry. Get the IP address for it (mine was 172.18.0.1) and try this for your alchemy URI **kylin://ADMIN@KYLIN@[Your_docker0_IP_Address]:7070/test**

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your superset_app network first.

use docker inspect [container name] i.e.

```
docker inspect superset_app
```

in my case, it is running in `superset_default` network

```
 "Networks": {
                "superset_default": {
                    .....
                }
            }
```

Next, you need to connect your kylin docker container to this network i.e.

```
docker network connect superset_default kylin
```

**kylin** is your container name.

Now, your superset_app and kylin container has been exposed within the same network. You can docker inspect your kylin container

```
docker inspect kylin
```

and find the **IPAddress**

```
"Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    ....
                },
                "superset_default": {
                    ...
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.5",
                    ...
                }
            }
```

In superset you can now connect your kylin docker container
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have hosted Dremio and Superset on an AKS Cluster in Azure and we are trying to connect Superset to the Dremio Database(Lakehouse) for fetching some dashboards. We have installed all the required drivers(arrowflight, sqlalchemy_dremio and unixodc/dev) to establish the connection.

Strangely we are able not able to connect to Dremio from the Superset UI using the connection strings:

```
dremio+flight://admin:password@dremiohostname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:32010/dremio
dremio://admin:adminpass@dremiohostname.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com:31010/databaseschema.dataset/dremio?SSL=0
```

Here’s the error:

*(builtins.NoneType) None\n(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)", "error_type": "GENERIC_DB_ENGINE_ERROR", "level": "error", "extra": {"engine_name": "Dremio", "issue_codes": [{"code": 1002, "message": "Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected error."}]}}]*

However, while trying from inside the Superset pod, using this python script [here][1] 5, the connection goes through without any issues.

PS - One point to note is that, we have not enabled SSL certificates for our hostnames.